# Django Channels group send (exclude the data sender)

Tags: django-channels

I'm using Django channels as an intermediate agent, which passes data from one browser(parent/sender) to other connected browsers(children/receivers). And in my consumers, I do a channel_layer.group_send(data) once data are received from the parent browser, so that children browsers can get the data from redis channel later.

However, what I really want is the data passed to the channel should be received by all the children, except the parent browser. My question is, how to exclude the data sender in the group?

Comment: seems that the data sender will receive the data anyway, but a solution could be using some local variables in frontend to decide whether the sender actually gets the data.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, django channels does not offer a filtering like that. I have solved the problem by checking in the chat_message function whether the current connection is the sender.

```
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        # Send message to room group

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.GROUP_NAME,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'data': text_data_json,
                'sender_channel_name': self.channel_name
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):

        # send to everyone else than the sender
        if self.channel_name != event['sender_channel_name']:
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
```

Comment: What if I'm doing the group send outside the consumer? How do I access the channel name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm end up using session id to exclude sender in consumer (group send *outside* the consumer):

in application:

```
def emit_websocket_update_info():
    sender_sessionid = info.context.COOKIES["sessionid"]
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        GraphQLUpdatesConsumer.group_name,
        {   
            "type": GraphQLUpdatesConsumer.mutation_handler,
            "text": json.dumps({"conditions": time.time()}),
            "sender_sessionid": sender_sessionid,
        },  
    )
```

in consumer:

```
async def mutation_event(self, event):
    # send to all except sender itself...
    if self.scope["cookies"]["sessionid"] != event["sender_sessionid"]:
        await self.send(text_data=event["text"])
```